# How to subscribe to Salesforce Developer Newsletter

Tags: administration

i'm wondering how to subscribe to the Developer Newsletter. I stumbled upon this page [Salesforce Developer Newsletter](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/News) where it says:

> Have Salesforce Developer Newsletter delivered to your inbox as soon as it's published. The Salesforce Developer Newsletter is a free benefit of Salesforce Developers membership.

I have a developer account but do not get the newsletter. Does anyone know hot to subscribe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into your Developer org. Go to the User record and scroll to the bottom. You will see newsletter settings there.

Comment: Thx for your help. Both newsletter and admin newsletter was checked. Still wondering why i am not getting the newsletter. So i unchecked both options ... saved ... checked it again and saved. Hopefully this will result in getting the newsletter ;-)

Comment: Check your spam folder?

Comment: Of course i did that ;-). I also checked that i added my email address correctly.